# a security exception in silverlight

Tags: security, silverlight-4.0

when I want to access **other website** in silverlight. it throw the security exception.

I look over the related forums, not find the right answer. please help me.

following block is my code:

```
            RequestState re = new RequestState();
            HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp.Create(new Uri("http://www.baidu.com"));
            request.Method = "Get";
            re.request = request;
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(RespCallback), re);
```

Comment: (+1 jjrdk) baidu.com has to explicitly allow you to access their site from your silverlight app using a clientaccesspolicy.xml file embedded at the root of their domain.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the site that you are trying to send a request to does not support cross domain requests.

You can read more about how to support cross domain requests here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(v=vs.95).aspx